# Run a Powershell script independently of C# application

Tags: c#, powershell

The aim of the code is: To pass an integer value of seconds into the Powershell script which will then be used to tell the Powershell script to wait and then restart the console application.

The problem: The Powershell script instance exists inside of the application. This means that the application waits until the script is finished when I want to exit the application and leave the script running.

```
PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
psExec.AddCommand(@powershellScriptLocation);
psExec.AddArgument(Convert.ToInt32(CalculateTimeToWait().TotalSeconds));
psExec.Invoke();
```

Comment: you would want to schedule a job for that or use background powershell jobs

Comment: You could simply try to use `Process.Start()` and launch the script using `PowerShell.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need something like this :)

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "pathToYourScript and args");
var process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
```